# prove ABCD is also a square

Tags: geometry

What we know is that:
[1. ABCD is a quadrilateral. 
2. The red area is a square. 
3. AH=BE=CF=DG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs71q.jpg)

[image]

The question is prove that ABCD is also a square.
I have realised that the four triangles here AHG, DGF, EFC and HBE have the same length hypotenuse and also AH = DG = CF = BE, so if I can prove ∠ A, B, C, D are 90°, then four triangles are congruent. Then I will know that four sides, AB,BC,CD,DA are the same length then I can prove it. 
The problem is that I dont know how to prove angle A,B,C,D are 90 degree. 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi NickMan and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Beautiful problem!

Comment: @Evargalo I have made some editings

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Thanks for your suggestion and I made some editings to illustrate my thoughts...

Answer (score 2):

If one among the angles at $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ is a right angle, then it is easy to prove they are all right angles and $ABCD$ is a square. Suppose then none of them is a right angle: at least one of them ($\angle GAH$, for instance) must then be obtuse. I'll show that this leads to a contradiction.

Let $N$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $G$ to line $AH$. As $\angle GAH>90°$ then $AH<NH$.

Let $M$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $E$ to line $BH$: we have then $EM\le EB$. But triangles $EMH$ and $HNG$ are congruent (because they have $\angle NGH=\angle MHE=\pi/2-\alpha$, $\angle NHG=\angle MEH=\alpha$ and $GH=HE$), thus:
$$
AH < NH = EM \le EB
$$
which is in contradiction with the hypothesis $AH=EB$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! You said triangles EMH and HNG are congruent because they have the same angles 90° and EH=GH... If the hypotenuse and one leg of a right triangle are equal to the hypotenuse and one leg of another right triangle, then the two right triangles are congruent.  EH=GH but what is the one leg of the triangle ?

Comment: "They have the same angles" means all their angles are equal pairwise: $\angle NGH=\angle MHE = 90°-\alpha$, and so on.

Comment: In other words: triangles $NGH$ and $BHE$ have $\angle NGH=\angle MHE$, $\angle NHG=\angle MEH$ and $GH=HE$. They are then congruent by ASA.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination, now I understand...you provide the very first solution that I can totally understand under this question. People were trying to prove triagles FCE=EBH=HAG=GDF but i just dont see how this could be done. Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: prove that the triangles $$FCE=EBH=HAG=GDF$$ are congruent

Comment: Sonnhard I think we'll see it after the proof that $ABCD$ is square.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought in the beginning, but I dont know how to prove the ∠A = ∠B= ∠C=∠D = 90°

Answer (score -1):

Hint: extend side $AD$ and $EF$. Let's say they intersect at point $X$. Then you can see that $\angle{XFG}=90°$ and $\angle{DXF}\cong\angle{AGH}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I still have no idea how to proceed ... If I can prove triangle AHC and triangle CXF are similar, then I can say ∠A = ∠XFG=90°... but how?

Answer (score -1):

Scheme of the proof:

- If $ABCD$ is rectangle, then it is easy to show that it is a square too (congruent triangles).
- If $ABCD$ isn't rectangle, then one of angles $A,B,C,D$ is obtuse one.
  W.l.o.g., $A>90^{\circ}$.

  - Then the distance from the line $AB$ to point $E$ is greater than $|AH|$.
  - So, $|BE|>|AH|$; contradiction.

---

More detailed:

first, draw the case with right angle $\angle A$:

[image: Illustration 1]

note that:

- point $A$ is on the semicircle $GAH$ (with diameter $GH$);
- line $GA$ is tangent to orange circle;
- line $AB$ is tangent to blue circle;
- $|AH|=|BE|$.

Now, build point $A'$ such that $|AH|=|A'H|$ and $\angle GA'H>90^{\circ}$:

[image: Illustration 2]

Point $A'$ belongs to orange circumference, and is inside the semicircle $GAH$ (inside $\triangle GAH$ too).

 So $\angle A'HG<\angle AHG$, hence ray $A'H$ cannot intersect blue circle.

So any segment $B'E$ (where $B'$ belongs to the ray $A'H$) has length greater than $|BE|$.

Here we came to contradiction: if $\angle GA'H$ is obtuse, then $|B'E|>|A'H|$.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. But how I can prove these four triangles are congruent?  If I can prove the ∠A = ∠B= ∠C=∠D = 90° then it would be easy.

Comment: If assume that $ABCD$ isn't rectangle, then we have contradiction: $|EB|>|AH|$. Therefore, $ABCD$ must be rectangle (otherwise we will have contradiction), and (see p.1) hence is a square.

Comment: If we use the picture from Aretino then the distance from the line AB to point E is ME, how do you claim ME is greater than AF?

Comment: @NickMan, I updated my answer with illustrations now. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: @NickMan, my fault... I had to say " then $ME$ is greater than $AH$" ($AH$, not $AF$). Now all is corrected.

Comment: Thanks for making the drawing and explanation! So first, i draw semicircle GAH (with diameter GH), then I will find a point A on the semicircle so that it becomes a right angle ∠A. Then if i draw a orange circle with AH as radius, then line GA is tangent to orange circle. Then I extend this AH to AB, where ∠ABE is 90°.Then the line AB is tangent to blue circle whose radius is BE. Now my questions is : how do you know |AH|=|BE|?

Comment: @NickMan, I place point B at the distance $|AG|$ from the point $H$.
Then $\triangle AHG = \triangle BEH$ (since $|GA|=|HB|$, $|GH|=|HE|$ and $\angle BHE=
180^{\circ}-\angle GHE -\angle AHG = 180^{\circ}-90^{\circ}-\angle AHG = \angle AGH$).